# Palindrome Linked List Python explanation

Tags: python, algorithm, linked-list

Hi I am trying to solve the palindrome linked list problem from leetcode. I have produced a solution but I am unsure why it is incorrect. It would be really appreciated with someone can explain my misconception to me.

Question:
Given the head of a singly linked list, return true if it is a palindrome or false otherwise. Full description can be found at https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-linked-list/

Here is my incorrect attempt (which looks sort of similar to the real solution)

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next


class Solution:
    # returns bool true or false
    def isPalindrome(self, head):

        # reverse the linked list
        # define another same head for the reversion 
        reversedhead = head
        # Define a previous to invert the link
        prev = None
        # while head is not None
        while reversedhead:
            # temp variable
            current = reversedhead
            reversedhead = reversedhead.next
            current.next = prev
            prev = current

        while head:
            if prev.val != head.val:
                return False
            prev = prev.next
            head = head.next

        return True
```

Here is a solution that I found online:

```
class Solution:
    # returns bool true or false
    def isPalindrome(self, head):
        slow = head
        # find the mid node
        while fast and fast.next:
            fast = fast.next.next
            slow = slow.next
        # reverse the second half
        node = None
        while slow:
            nxt = slow.next
            slow.next = node
            node = slow
            slow = nxt
        # compare the first and second half nodes
        while node: # while node and head:
            if node.val != head.val:
                return False
            node = node.next
            head = head.next
        return True
```

My code looks sort of similar but it is wrong. The order of my statements inside the while loop is different that the order of the statements in the right solution. For the head [1, 1, 2, 1], my solution failed the test. My output was true but the expected output is false.

I think I have issues with understanding the head and node concept? The head is just the first node of the linked list right? In this case the first node/head would be 1?

I tried to debug on my own before asking, but pycharm is returning an error which I don't understand. How do I use [1, 1, 2, 1] as input to my solution?

```
q = Solution()
print(q.isPalindrome(ListNode(1, 1)))

reversedhead = reversedhead.next
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'next'
```

Comment: Write some test on your own and try to find a failing one. Than start debugging.

Comment: @MrSmith42 Thanks I have tried to do that but I am not sure how to write the inputs. I will edit my question.

Comment: @MrSmith42 Hi Mr Smith I have added the errors I faced when trying to create some test cases on pycharm. How do I use my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea seems to be the following:

1. reverse the list
2. walk forward along the list and at the same time walk backwards by the reversed list
3. If each compared value is the same, then it is a palindrome

The logical error is in step 2: you cannot walk forward anymore through the list, because it has been reversed. There is only one list. `head` is now the tail of that list, and thus `head.next` is `None`. So this loop will get into trouble in its second iteration, as at that point `head` is `None`.

The second, correct, algorithm, only reverses the second half of the list, so now there is a first half that can be traversed in forward manner, and a second half that can be traversed in backward manner. That way it will indeed work.

Alternatively, your idea would work if you would clone all nodes without mutating the original linked list nodes, and would reverse link those. Obviously that will allocate O(n) of memory, and is therefore less optimal than the correct solution you already quoted:

```
    def isPalindrome(self, head: Optional[ListNode]) -> bool:
        reversedhead = None
        current = head
        while current:
            reversedhead = ListNode(current.val, reversedhead)
            current = current.next

        while head:
            if reversedhead.val != head.val:
                return False
            reversedhead = reversedhead.next
            head = head.next

        return True
```

As to testing this in a local environment: you should not pass a list to your function, but an instance of `ListNode`. While LeetCode does this for you before calling your function, in a local environment you'll have to prepare the input yourself.

Check out my answer on [AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'val' in linked list LeetCode challenge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72598123/5459839) for how you can do that.

Comment: Hi trincot, thanks for the help. I thought I created ```reversedhead = head``` which created another head to be reversed and retained the initial head to move forward. How can I create a duplicate of the head to be reversed? Can you also explain the edited part? ie I was trying to create my own test cases to test my solution, but I ran into some errors as shown in the question. Many thanks again.

Comment: @trincot Doesn't this use twice as much memory as already occupied by the existing linked list?

Comment: @OldBill, yes it does, but see the comment from the Asker above: *"...How can I create a  **duplicate** of the head to be reversed?"*. This is the only reason I added that to my answer, as I could not post all that code in a comment. This is indeed not advisable, but the asker already has the optimal code that does not duplicate the list.

Comment: @OldBill I requested trincot to provide a solution (which is sub-optimal) that I wanted as I wanted to see how I could implement my idea. thanks.

Comment: Hi trincot, I have looked at your answer from your another post and it works great in my local machine and I can finally create my own test cases. Thanks. I have one more question, is head the first node of a linked list? A head is a node right? If so, why does leetcode asks for ```head``` instead of asking for a linked list ? For example, from the leetcode website: ```def isPalindrome(self, head: Optional[ListNode]) -> bool:```. leetcode is asking for a head, but I have to use a linked list as an argument to the parameter before it would work?

Comment: Yes, the head is the first node, but as that node provides a reference to the next node, and that one provides a reference to the third node,...etc, this head is enough to have access to the whole list.

Comment: Maybe I should clarify more. LeetCode problems on linked lists only work with a node class, not with a separate linked-list class. So for LeetCode problems you always get the head node. If it is `None`, then it means the list is empty. In other contexts it is often more useful to work with a second class, a linked list class, which can contain the head reference as an attribute, and possibly have other attributes, like the tail, the size,... This is not what is happening on LeetCode: there the concept of linked list is simple, and the head node is all that is needed to know about a linked list

Comment: @trincot So for example, in other contexts I should implement the ```class Node:``` and ```class UnorderedList:``` or ```class OrderedList:```? And I can have different methods within the linked list class like ```.add(item)``` or something like that? Yeah this is what I am seeing from my textbooks too. From my textbook, I have to define 2 classes: the Node and the type of linked list and each has it own methods. Anyways I think i have finally understand the problem. Many thanks again!

Comment: Yes, it is like you say.